# Why doesn't the Graph API return the newest photos a user has been tagged in?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

About a dozen users have complained that my app that fetches photos they are tagged in is not fetching the most recent photos... it is a simple call.

http://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

Is there any way to get the newest photos? Some sort of Order By? Or is there some kind of delay between tags and access via the API?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem but it's with photos that are weeks old still not appearing. I can see the correct photos on the Facebook pages of me and my friends but my site and the graph explorer tool (using FQL and Graph API) both aren't returning the most recent photos. For me it's only been happening over the last month. Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some goofy stuff going on with the Open Graph API over the last week where objects that belong to a record are not getting returned with a valid API call. My issue went away on its own this weekend.

There is some delay in the best case between when an item gets tagged and it shows up on all the FB servers. The server that is serving your user's page to them will be different than the one serving the Graph API response. In my experience it is usually less than 30 mins, for the update but I've seen it take up to 6 hours.

As far as I can tell, you need to use an FQL call to explicitly order the results you get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of photos with tags ordered by time by using this FQL query:

```
SELECT subject, object_id, created FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = USER_ID
```

where subject is the user id of the user who was tagged, object id is the id of the photo object, created is the creation time (as Unix timestamp), and photo_tag is the [FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/). This will return a list ordered by time with newest first.

From there, you can get the photo url using the object_id like this:

```
SELECT src, src_big, src_small FROM photo WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID
```

which will give you urls to the photo in 3 differen sizes. This uses the [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) photo table.